# Jquery multiselect plugin

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, multi-select

I am using the following jquery multiselect autocomplete plugin

http://wilkerlucio.github.com/jquery-multiselect/

I want to add values to the multiselect on a button click, but couldn't find such a method. Does anyone know one? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just assign a click event handler to your button. If clicked, add values to your list/array of values your multiselect component is using.

```
$('#buttonId').click(function() {
  // add values to your list/array the multiselect uses
});
```

Reference: [jQuery API - .click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)